# Importing linetypes from AutoCAD to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, style, autocad

I am creating a map that has property lines, streams, sanitary sewer, railroads etc.

I would like to apply lineytpes that are similar to those of AutoCAD, if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcMap renders symbology similar to that of the source AutoCAD source file when added to ArcMap.

When a DWG/DXF is added to ArcMap this is called a "CAD Layer". This layer is different from a regular feature class: it has a different data type and a different set of symbology (as well as other) properties.  Unfortunately for some unknown reason, CAD Layer symbology cannot be imported into ArcMap layers.

You will need to create the symbology manually or use similar symbology that is available. In fact even CAD layers symbology saved from a CAD layer inside ArcMap is not compatible with native (ArcGIS) feature class layers (even when you Import a CAD layer into a geodatabase and add it to the same map, you will not be able to to import the symbology from the CAD Layer).

Comment: Do you know of a template that is supported in ArcMAP that is similar to CAD, specifically utility layers, for example electrical would look like ----E----

Comment: In ArcMap there are similar symbols to CAD standards and specifically in your case Utilities standards in the Style Manager window.

Click Customize > Style Manager.. > Styles... (On the Right of box), A Style References Box pops up, and you can choose Utilities for your case.  They also have symbol standards for Mining, Survey, Petroleum, Soils, Transportation... a lot of things..

After your selected references click Add Style to List.. if you have an existing .STYLE file, if not you can create one.

When you click on your linework suggestions will now pop up in the Symbol Selector

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Jakub there seems to be no automatic way of doing this. ESRI has the **ESRI-CAD** style for ArcGIS features to use, but it lacks a lot of the symbology used in AutoCAD (such as "---e---" mentioned by Matt).

Here is a [link about ArcGIS 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=3223&pid=3222&topicname=Symbolizing_CAD_features) which mentions ESRI-CAD. And here's a [more recent post](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1794) to ESRI Mapping Center about it, which point towards ESRI-CAD as well.